# How to share MS Access 2010 database over the Internet

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have an Access 2010 database that I want to split into two (front and back ends) and share it over the Internet. I have access to MS Windows 2003 Server where I installed the ODBC driver for .accdb files. But now I don't know the next step. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you have Sharepoint, you can do a lot with Access 2010 and the internet. Look out for posts and articles by Albert Kallal also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752154/access-services-and-sharepoint-2010-need-info

Comment: Someone has solved this problem, and offers it as a service here: http://eqldata.com/onweb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is very chatty.  You won't want the data source to be over the Internet.  You might consider giving a virtual terminal login for whoever needs to see the database.  Windows Server 2003 allows two terminal connections by default without any terminal services CAL's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to have the database somewhere outside the webroot and access it over the Internet?

Comment: @Baha The problem is the front-end, not the back-end.  Your front-end will be very inefficient if you try to connect to a database that's not directly on the local network with the Access application.  You will need to use a different technology for the front-end (at least).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652046/is-it-possible-to-host-access-forms-online.

Comment: Thanks again. The only reason I chose access over other databases was its relative easiness to generate reports. It may be inefficient but I want to give it a try and see it for myself.

Comment: @Baha Sure. You will need to provide a way to get to the backend over the Internet.  Like place it in your c:\inetpub\myapp\myapp.accdb.  Then setup an IIS website to connect.  Then lookup the odbc connection string on http://connectionstrings.com/ and use the path to your application in IIS.  All of these things can be Googled for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. I have another question though. The server is currently running some kind of jsp website, so I guess it's an Oracle web server, not IIS. Is it OK if I install IIS and use it at the same time without inturrupting the existing server?

Comment: @Baha Doesn't matter what kind of server, just so you can get access to the .accdb file over the Internet.  Somehow you will need to link to the file.

Comment: The two default Terminal Server logons are required to be adminstrative. On a domain controller, that probably doesn't mean domain admin, just local admin, but it's still way more privileges than I'd want to give people for running even a test app. I would only use those to demonstrate proof of concept, as developer.

Comment: David, are you saying it is not possible to share an access db with people who are not admins?