# Using MS-ACCESS split database over internet

Tags: ms-access, odbc, client-server

I am working on a database that is expected to operate over multiple distributed locations in a client-server model. I am limited to MSACCESS and currently using a split database for a local network.

Can we extend this split database over the internet securely. Note we cannot employ more sophisticated solutions such as MSSQL or sharepoint.

We have a fixed IP, however found no examples of using MSACCESS on the internet and therefore not much information about security.

Came across this thread: [How to share MS Access 2010 database over the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044680/how-to-share-ms-access-2010-database-over-the-internet)

but we have no virtual terminal login.

Thanks

Comment: You really really need to investigate an alternative database solution, this is really the wrong way to try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out my article here:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html

In the above I explain your options. I mean, if you have a server anyplace (as you plan), then I see little reason to not use a free edition of SQL server for the back end.

Also, I not sure why you think some technologies like using SharePoint or office 365 (cloud) are expensive? The basic edition of SharePoint is free with any server edition of windows (2008 R2 last time I looked was under $500).

And you can get office 365 plans staring at $6 that supports not only you placing your data tables in the cloud and linking your MS Access VBA front end to those tables on o365, but for that same low price you ALSO can create web forms in Access and publish them to office 365. The following video of mine shows this new ability for access 2010:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

So a $6 per month plan to do this is going to be less than one service call for any of your computers.

Comment: The article was very enlightening for the different connectivity options. The recommendation for the MsSQL make greater sense now.

Answer (score 2):

MS Access is not designed for use across the internet, thus why there is no native in-built functionality.

One of few options is for user's from multiple locations to log in via a VPN connection to the server where the database file is stored. However this is still not a good idea as when you introduce a large distance for data to travel, you risk incomplete or corrupt data, not to mention the headache of a multi user environment based on this model.

You mention not been able to use MsSql but haven't stated why, if it is down to cost or licensing issue's etc then you may be able to consider using the free express version of MsSql instead.

Comment: The use of MsSQL is due cost. I have not considered the MsSQL express. I am also assuming that there is a way to connect the forms (Access Front-end) to a MsSQL backend, or is it the same issues for as a full access solution.

Basically we have existing access forms, and staff who are familiar with Access but not much else.

Comment: And don't forget you can also migrate your data to other free engines, like MySql or PostgreSql. While MsSql Express has advantages here, you're not trapped into a pure MS solution.

Comment: Seconding Matt's answer, you can use the free SQL Server Express and also the free Studio Express as a develoment environment. I work with Access, and if there's a way you can avoid my Hell I recommend it highly!

Comment: @CarlF – hard to avoid using Access when the application + code + user interface been built using Access? SQL server does not let you create forms.  I mean if you build a system with vb.net, c#.net, or MS Access, you THEN have to go out and choose the database system you plan to use with that system. With a tool like MS Access you build the UI and code, but like most dev tools you THEN have to go out and choose a database. Perhaps you meant JET or ACE, but SQL server express is not tool that lets you build the application + UI like Access does.

Comment: @CarlF: true, but for SOME tasks, an ADP is so much easier ! (e.g.:  copy a table with just ctrl+C, ctrl+V)

Comment: @iDevlop I'm on board with the first point, I got lost in MS from the question but yes MySQL or PostgreSQL are also really good free alternative's, and I think Postgre has the highest data limit of any of the free one's, different features available in each so I guess comes down to preference : )

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, I agree that SQL server is not a unified UI/DB builder. Note that I mentioned Studio Express. More complex development, more elegant final result. I use Access myself but I don't think it's perfect for every project.